# How to set image path dynamically in MVC 3 RAZOR

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, dynamic, razor, path

How to set image path dynamically for following:

```
<img src="/Images/Model" + @item.ModelImagePath />
```

**"/Images/Model"** this path is fixed, rest of the path comes from [**ModelImagePath**] column of Model DBTable.

Please guide me how to set the path dynamically in View.

And is there any **Html helper tag to display image** available in MVC RZOR?

Note: i have similar type of problem as described in

[How to use/pass hidden field value in ActionLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464003/how-to-use-pass-hidden-field-value-in-actionlink)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/Images/Model/{0}", item.ModelImagePath))"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already saved the entire path into the table, follow it

```
<img src="@Url.Content(String.Format("{0}",item.ModelImagePath))"/>
```

or

```
<img src="@Url.Content(item.ModelImagePath)" style="width:100px;height:100px"/>
```